# Unable to update form data in firestore database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

In my react/nextjs app, I am trying to update a field in the 'users' collection in my firestore db using a form.

**WriteOrgToCloudFirestore**

```
import { db } from "@/lib/firebase/initFirebase";
import { doc, updateDoc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useUser } from "@/lib/firebase/useUser";
import { useState } from "react";

const WriteOrgToCloudFirestore = () => {
  const { user } = useUser();

  const [orgName, setOrgName] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setOrgName(event.target.value);
  };

  const sendData = async () => {
    try {
      const userDoc = doc(db, "users", user.id);
      console.log('db',db);
      await setDoc(userDoc, {
        orgName: orgName,
      });
      alert("User Data was successfully sent to cloud firestore!");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      alert(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "5px 0" }}>
      <form onSubmit={sendData}>
        <input type="text"  value={orgName} onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="submit" style={{ width: "100%" }} value="send message" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default WriteOrgToCloudFirestore;
```

When I send the data, I am not getting an error message. However, no data is being written to the DB.

I have another write file which is almost the same but with prefilled data. If I manually update it with new string values, I see the updates in the "myCollections" collection in the firebase console:

```
import { db } from '@/lib/firebase/initFirebase'
import { doc, setDoc, Timestamp, GeoPoint } from "firebase/firestore"
import { useUser } from '@/lib/firebase/useUser'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'

const WriteToCloudFirestore = () => {
    const { user } = useUser()
    const sendData = async () => {
        try {
            const userDoc = doc(db, "myCollection", user.id)
            await updateDoc(userDoc, {
                string_data: 'Benjamin Carlson',
                number_data: 2,
                boolean_data: true,
                map_data: { stringInMap: 'Hi', numberInMap: 7 },
                array_data: ['text', 4],
                null_data: null,
                time_stamp: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00')),
                geo_point: new GeoPoint(34.714322, -131.468435)
            })
            alert('Data was successfully sent to cloud firestore!')
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            alert(error)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div style={{ margin: '5px 0' }}>
            <Button onClick={sendData} style={{ width: '100%' }}>Send Data To Cloud Firestore</Button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default WriteToCloudFirestore
```

When submitted, the alert is shown with the success message.

Though the files are nearly identical, I'm not sure why I am not able to see my submission in the *WriteOrgToCloudFirestore.js* file.

Comment: Can you log and check value of `user.id` before update/set?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes, when I console log user.id, it returns my userID and email from Google's provider service.

Comment: What is your goal for the `setDoc`? Is it for updating a document or creating a new document with a `custom id`? Can you try adding this code to check if what is creating a new document or overwriting an existing document:

.then(() => {
    getDoc(ref)
    .then((a) => {
        console.log(a.id, "=>", a.data())
    })
})